# contour plot with text

Tags: plotting

How can I plot this:

[image]

I tried this code but it didn't give the same output. Can you help?

[image]

The .nb file is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/82n37476dujn1mv/last2.nb?dl=0

Thx

Comment: Welcome on board. Usually we prefer the code to be in a format that easy for copy-paste rather than a link redirecting to dropbox. Can you please include your code in such a format in your post?

Comment: There is nothing in the image of the code you posted that shows these text and arrows being drawn. One way to add these is by using the `Text` command and the also using `Arrow` command. But you need to try these few times to get them in correct location. Another option is to edit the plot using Mathematica's edit plot tools, which could be this is what was done in the example you show. Either way, posting the code in plain text is better than posting an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] = (8/3)*x^3 - 4*x^2 + (1/2)*y^2 + 
      x*y^2*(y^2 - 2);

critPts = 
 Solve[{D[f[x, y], x] == 0, D[f[x, y], y] == 0}, {x, y}, Reals] /. 
  r_Root :> N[r]

(* {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> 1.10715, 
  y -> -0.879883}, {x -> 1.10715, y -> 0.879883}} *)

max = Select[
  critPts, (D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] /. #) < 
     0 &&
    (D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] /. #) < 0 &]

(* {} *)

min = Select[
  critPts, (D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] /. #) > 
     0 &&
    (D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] /. #) > 0 &]

(* {{x -> 1.10715, y -> -0.879883}, {x -> 1.10715, y -> 0.879883}} *)

saddle = Complement[critPts, max, min]

(* {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}} *)

ContourPlot[f[x, y], 
   {x, -0.5, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Contours -> 12,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 2,
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Red, Point[{x, y} /. min],
   Text["Potential well", {1.72, -1.9}],
   Arrow[{{1.72, -1.83}, #}] & /@ ({x, y} /. min),
   Darker[Green], Point[{x, y} /. saddle],
   Text["Saddle points", {1.72, 1.9}],
   Arrow[{{1.72, 1.83}, #}] & /@ ({x, y} /. saddle)}]
```

[image]

Comment: Super super. How did you get the value of Potential well and saddle point to be 1.72 and 1.9. Thx

Comment: The location of the saddle points are stored in the variable `saddle`, the point `{1.72, 1.9}` is an **arbitrary** location for the text "Saddle points". The location was chosen since it had a white background and would not interfere with the text. Likewise, the location of the potential wells are stored in the variable `min`. The text "Potential well" was **arbitrarily** placed in the white space at `{1.72, -1.9}`. Since the `ContourPlot` is symmetric, the **arbitrary** text locations were also chosen to be symmetric.

Comment: Got it Thank you.